# Varying video duration in MPEG-DASH streaming

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video.js, mpeg-dash

I have a use case where I need to provide playback speeds for a video up to 100x. Since most modern browsers don't support this and provide 4x max out of the box, I have encoded multiple video files using FFmpeg of speeds 10x, 25x, 50x, and 100x. I want to generate an MPEG dash stream for these files and use videojs to play it.

Here is the problem. As per my knowledge, MPEG dash was designed and developed to support ABR streaming which has an underlying assumption that the video stream length would not change (except in the case of live streaming where the MPD stream generation is dynamic). In my case, however, the only thing that's changing is video speed or fps, not the bitrate. The result of this is that although the videos play fine going faster or slower, the duration displayed in videojs player is not correct when a stream is switched from the speed selector and keeps updating as the video continues to buffer. The seek bar keeps updating accordingly as well which is bad user experience as it appears like a glitch and more importantly, the user can't seek the video beyond the point the video has been buffered.

The easiest solution that comes to my mind is that I ditch the MPEG dash and straight-up switch the video source in the videojs player but that isn't a seamless experience for two reasons:

1. The video would be loaded from scratch which could take longer on a slower network.
2. The duration is again absent until the video is loaded

Furthermore, MPEG dash is a standard for streaming globally and if I need to add DRM in the future, I would need the MPEG dash anyways.

What can be the possible solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saying that your multiple renditions are using different playback speeds, which as you highlight is not what a client will be expecting and hence will likely cause confusion.

Your use case is interesting - in theory a DASH or HLS client could be able to handle this if you added some custom functionality that was aware of the different bit rates, and so long as you are ok switching between speeds at the segment boundaries. It could be quit a bit of custom work, however.

Looking at alternatives, as you say, having separate videos will mean a startup delay.

One way you could avoid this is by having the videos preloaded but hidden. If you do this you will also likely need to have some link between the currently playing video and the hidden videos to load a buffer as the visible video plays back.

On the DRM side, you probably do not need to be restricted as the major DRM's are applied to the video tracks within the DASH or HLS stream, and you can similarly use DRM on a separate HLS or DASH stream or on a simple streamed MP4 file.